# Why is Spark textFile in Java to read .gz files much slower than using spark shell in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I used Spark shell (Spark 1.6.2) to run a very simple query to count the # of lines on a bunch of .gz files as following:

```
sc.textFile("s3a://bucket-name/prod/data-source/2017-05-05/*/").count
```

> 2017-06-06 21:33:21 INFO  SparkContext:58 - Created broadcast 2 from textFile at :28
>   2017-06-06 21:33:24 INFO  FileInputFormat:249 - Total input paths to process : 1700
>   2017-06-06 21:33:24 INFO  SparkContext:58 - Starting job: count at :28
>   2017-06-06 21:33:24 INFO  SparkContext:58 - Created broadcast 3 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
>   res1: Long = 433733191

It takes less than **10 seconds** to return the #.

But it takes about **3 minutes** when I used Java writing the same logic in a test application:

```
new SparkContextFactory(appName).textFile("s3a://bucket-name/prod/data-source/2017-05-05/*/").count()
```

Here is slice of output printout:

> 2017-06-06 22:40:20 INFO  Executor:58 - Running task 195.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 195)
>   2017-06-06 22:40:20 INFO  HadoopRDD:58 - Input split: s3a://bucket-name/prod/data-source/2017-05-05/20170505_1493980530/part-r-00095.gz:0+3732508
>   2017-06-06 22:40:20 INFO  CodecPool:181 - Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]
>   2017-06-06 22:40:21 INFO  Executor:58 - Finished task 194.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 194). 2336 bytes result sent to driver
>   2017-06-06 22:40:21 INFO  Executor:58 - Running task 196.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 196)
>   2017-06-06 22:40:21 INFO  HadoopRDD:58 - Input split: s3a://bucket-name/prod/data-source/2017-05-05/20170505_1493980530/part-r-00096.gz:0+3727204
>   2017-06-06 22:40:21 INFO  CodecPool:181 - Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]
>   2017-06-06 22:40:22 INFO  Executor:58 - Finished task 195.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 195). 2336 bytes result sent to driver
>   2017-06-06 22:40:22 INFO  Executor:58 - Running task 197.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 197)
>   2017-06-06 22:40:22 INFO  HadoopRDD:58 - Input split: s3a://bucket-name/prod/data-source/2017-05-05/20170505_1493980530/part-r-00097.gz:0+3734183
>   2017-06-06 22:40:22 INFO  CodecPool:181 - Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]
>   2017-06-06 22:40:22 INFO  Executor:58 - Finished task 196.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 196). 2336 bytes result sent to driver

There are multiple subfolders under s3a://bucket-name/prod/data-source/2017-05-05/, and each subfolder has hundreds of .gz files of about 4MB each.

What confused me is why there is so much time diff cost btw the 2 ways?
Appreciate if anybody could share some lights?

Comment: When you run in the shell, is the the very first thing you do after starting it?  Spark does some caching, so the files might already be loaded if it's not a brand new context.

Comment: @puhlen in Spark Shell, it's not cached unless you manually load it and specify it's cached.  So cache does not play a role here as I never cached it. And also it is the first statement I run after starting spark shell.

Comment: that's not actually true, spark does do some automatic caching during shuffle stages as well.  So it's certainly possible, especially if you are working in the shell, that things get cached without you realizing.  I don't think that can happen if you start a new shell so that's probably not it.

Comment: @puhlen Thanks, that's true.  Just found the issue. Its because of only driver is working to load files instead of 9 workers. It's strange that I submitted in cluster mode, why only driver is working?

Comment: OK, problem figured out.  Though I setup spark driver address as spark_master when submitting the Java job, I didn't realize that the "local" was setup as spark master in Java application internally.  It seems if they are configured in both places, Spark choose the one in Java application to run with.